# How to check current network id in C#?

Tags: c#, networking, ip, host

How to get current network ID using C#? I tried the code shown here, but it's returning IP address. What is the correct way to get current network id? Please help me with any sample code.

```
IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
IPAddress[] addr = hostEntry.AddressList;

var ip = addr.Where(x => x.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
             .FirstOrDefault();

return ip.ToString() ?? "";
```

Thanks!

Comment: to work out the network id, you'll need to know the subnet mask as well -- which isn't something that's readily available if it's not a network connection on your own machine.

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming you want an IPv4 network.

To support networks of different sizes, IPv4 networks are divided into 3 different address classes. Each class has a different network prefix.

**Class A (prefix of 8 bits (/8):**
255.0.0.0
start with 1 – 126

**Class B (/16):**
255.255.0.0
start with 128 – 191

**Class C (/24):**
255.255.255.0
addresses that start with 192 – 223

class D and E is the rest of the networks but thats not important for now. For more information you can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/tcpip-addressing-and-subnetting).

Basically the first octet of an ip adress can determine the network class. A simple code sample provided [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/razan/finding-subnet-mask-from-ip4-address-using-c).

```
    public static string ReturnSubnetmask(string ipaddress)
{
    var firstOctet = ReturnFirtsOctet(ipaddress);
    if (firstOctet is >= 0 and <= 127)
    {
        return "255.0.0.0";
    }
    else if (firstOctet is >= 128 and <= 191)
    {
        return "255.255.0.0";
    }
    else if (firstOctet is >= 192 and <= 223)
    {
        return "255.255.255.0";
    }
    else
    {
        return "0.0.0.0";
    }
}
public static uint ReturnFirtsOctet(string ipAddress)
{
    var iPAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
    var byteIP = iPAddress.GetAddressBytes();
    var ipInUint = (uint)byteIP[0];
    return ipInUint;
}
```

Comment: Network address classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (two years _before_ the commercial Internet in 1995) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). We have not had network address classes in this century.